# Butterfly plot using ggplot to show fill in each arm and different coloring scheme for each arm

Tags: r, ggplot2

To build on top of my exciting code for butterfly using ggplot, where fill is being used to differentiate categories in each arm, how can I have different coloring schemes for each arm. For example, blue coloring scheme for Arm 1 and red coloring scheme for Arm 2 while still maintaining category differentiation in each arm? Here's my current code. Hence, also resulting in one legend for each arm.

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = term)) +
  geom_bar(data=tmp[tmp$arm=="2",], aes(y=pct, fill=cat,), stat = 'identity') +
  geom_bar(data=tmp[tmp$arm=="1",], aes(y=-pct, fill=cat), stat="identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="white", lwd=1) +
  coord_flip(ylim=c(-18, 18)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-18, 18, 2), labels = c('18', '16', '14', '12', '10', '8', '6', '4', '2', '0', '2', '4', '6', '8', '10', '12', '14', '16', '18')) +
  labs(y="Relative Frequency (%)", x="", title = ~ atop(bold("Title"), 
                                                        scriptstyle(italic('Title 2'))),
       subtitle = "Arm 1                                                  Arm 2 ") + labs(caption = ' ') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.3), legend.title = element_text(size = 25), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'), 
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = 'black'),
        axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = 'black'),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 10, face = 'bold'), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20, face = 'bold'),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.1, 'cm'), legend.background = element_rect(color = 'white'),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, 'cm'), legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 25)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(charcoal, teal, blue)) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Category")) +
  theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(size=12, hjust=0.5, face="bold", color=blue))
```

And the resulting plot[image]

This is an example of what I'm trying to recreate.
[image]

Here's the sample data.

```
structure(list(id = structure(c("2005", "2005", "3001", "3001", 
"4002", "4007", "4008", "4001", "4001", "4011", "4016", "4016", 
"0001", "0001", "0001", "0004", "0004", "0004", "0004", "0004", 
"3001", "5002", "5002", "5002", "5002", "5003", "8006", "8006", 
"8006", "9001", "9003", "9004", "9004", "9004", "9004", "9004", 
"7001", "7001", "7001", "7002", "7002", "7002", "7002", "7005", 
"8001", "8001", "1001", "3009", "0001", "1001", "1001", "1001", 
"1001", "1003", "2001", "2002", "2001", "1004", "1005", "2001", 
"2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2007", "2008", "2008", 
"3004", "7002", "8002", "8004", "8004", "9001", "0001", "0005", 
"0005", "1001", "1001", "1001", "2002", "2003", "1001", "1001", 
"4003", "4003", "4003", "4005", "7003"), label = "Subject name or identifier", format.sas = "$"), 
    arm = c("2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", 
    "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
    "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", 
    "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2"), term = c("Myo", "Thy", 
    "Hea", "Ras", "Imm", "Bul", "Hyp", "Pru", "Ras", "Res", "Pru", 
    "Ras", "Hyp", "Pne", "Ras", "Gen", "Hyp", "Pru", "Ras", "Sto", 
    "Ery", "Dia", "Pru", "Ras", "Typ", "Tra", "Int", "Ras", "Whe", 
    "Pne", "Der", "Chi", "Ery", "Flu", "Hea", "Pyr", "Bro", "Pne", 
    "Pru", "Hyp", "Pne", "Pru", "Ras", "Ras", "Acu", "Pru", "Ras", 
    "Acu", "Hyp", "Hyp", "Int", "Pne", "Pru", "Pru", "Ras", "Ras", 
    "Inf", "Flu", "Ras", "Con", "Dia", "Dru", "Pne", "Pru", "Pru", 
    "Sto", "Chr", "Pru", "Pne", "Pne", "Ras", "Hyp", "Pne", "Pru", 
    "Pne", "Hyp", "Ras", "Hyp", "Pru", "Sto", "Col", "Int", "Hyp", 
    "Urt", "Int", "Myo", "Pru", "Pru", "Rhi"), cat = c("5", "3", 
    "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "5", 
    "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
    "5", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1"), n = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), N = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), N.arm = c(50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L
    ), pct = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), tpct = c(1, 
    1, 2, 11, 1, 1, 8, 16, 4, 1, 16, 4, 2, 10, 11, 1, 8, 16, 
    11, 3, 2, 1, 16, 11, 1, 1, 4, 11, 1, 10, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 10, 16, 8, 10, 16, 4, 4, 2, 16, 11, 2, 8, 8, 4, 10, 16, 
    16, 11, 11, 1, 2, 11, 1, 1, 1, 10, 16, 16, 3, 1, 16, 10, 
    10, 11, 8, 10, 16, 10, 8, 11, 8, 16, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 
    16, 16, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -89L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option. By creating an interaction category between `arm` and `cat` you have a variable to map to your fill aesthetic. You could also create this directly in `ggplot` instead: `fill = interaction(arm, cat)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tmp %>%
  mutate(pct = if_else(arm == 1, -pct, pct)) %>%
  unite(col = 'Category',
        c(arm, cat), remove = FALSE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = term, x = pct, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = 'white', lwd=1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('indianred2','firebrick1','orangered',
                               'lightskyblue','dodgerblue2','blue')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-18,18,2),
                     labels = c('18', '16', '14', '12', '10', '8', '6', '4', '2', '0',
                                '2', '4', '6', '8', '10', '12', '14', '16', '18')) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
  labs(y="Relative Frequency (%)", x="", title = ~ atop(bold("Title"), 
                                                        scriptstyle(italic('Title 2'))),
       subtitle = "Arm 1                                                  Arm 2 ",
       caption = ' ') +
  theme(plot.subtitle =  element_text(size=12, hjust=0.5, face="bold", color='blue'),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'),
        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.3), legend.title = element_text(size = 25), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'), 
        axis.line.x = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = 'black'),
        axis.line.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = 'black'),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 10, face = 'bold'), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20, face = 'bold'),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.1, 'cm'), legend.background = element_rect(color = 'white'),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, 'cm'), legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 25))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>